# Ordering food from a menu in a restaurant

Tags: mandarin, food, politeness

How should I order food from a menu in a restaurant?

In English I'd usually say something like 'I'll have the beef' or 'one of these and two of those' while pointing.

In the past in China I have simply pointed and said `一个` or `这个`, but I imagine that is not quite correct :)

Comment: As a cultural aside, does anyone else find it odd how waiters/waitresses on the mainland will stand beside you, waiting with pen poised on notepad while you peruse the menu? Some menus can be quite large, and I always feel guilty if I take too long!

Comment: I also get annoyed by that. You can always tell them `我们还没决定` so they go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is correct when you point and say "这个", but Chinese speakers often use "一份" instead of "一个". The complete sentence may look like "我想要一份XXX" or “我要这个”.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: The meaning of 一份 would be something like "one portion of" btw.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chang's answer, you may also ask in the following manner:

请给我一份牛排套餐，外加这道菜，还有那两样。

Comment: So I can use `外加` and `还有` to join different items I am ordering?

Comment: @Cocowalla, absolutely.

Comment: You could also use 来, as in 来一份牛排套餐.

Comment: @jogloran I've never seen `来` used like that - I feel another question coming on!

Comment: 来 seems to be more common from my experience. Just to confuse the matter further, you could also say 请给我来一份牛排套餐

Comment: @jogloran I've also seen `来一份`. For the doubters, there _is_ a company whose name is totally a pun on that: (来伊份)[http://baike.baidu.com/view/1370562.htm]

Comment: I don't know if it's a Northern/Southern Mandarin thing, but I've only heard this up north. I don't think this (or its Cantonese reflex `lai4`/`lei4`) is used in Cantonese for this purpose.